# ASCII to HEX conversion issue in C

Tags: c, hex, ascii, fread

I have a function like this:

```
int GetBytes(char *loc, int Bytes)
{
  int BytesRead=0;
  int j = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int fileloc = 0;
  unsigned char TmpLoc[500];
  unsigned char TmpLoc1[500];

  strcpy(loc,"");
  Bytes = Bytes / 2;
  BytesRead = fread(TmpLoc, 1, Bytes,PrcFile); 
  /*Start of conversion*/
  if (ebcidic_flag[0] == 'Y')
  {
    for (i=0; i < BytesRead; i++)
    {
      j = i * 2;
      sprintf(TmpLoc1, "%x", TmpLoc[i]);
      if (strlen(TmpLoc1) < 2)
      {
        strcat(&loc[j], "0");
        j++;
      }
      strcat (&loc[j],TmpLoc1);
    }
  }
  for (i=0;i<(BytesRead*2);i++)
  {
    if ((loc[i] >= 0x60) & (loc[i] <= 0x7a))
      loc[i] = loc[i] & 0xdf;
  }
  /*End of conversion*/
  TotalBytes = TotalBytes + BytesRead;
  return (BytesRead * 2);
}
```

The issue when I comment the conversion logic, `fread` reads whole file.
But when conversion logic is activated the `fread` does not read the whole file.
For example if I have a file of 30000 bytes, it may only reads 1210 bytes and then return zero.
Is there any issue with my conversion logic ?
**It exactly reads 16382 as per requirement after that it reads only 2 bytes and return 0. I tried different files but the result is same**

Comment: Can you please format your code in a more decent fashion?

Comment: Did you intend both `for` loops to be executed `if (ebcidic_flag[0] =='Y')`?

Comment: This is not part of code. Let me rmove it.

Comment: I formatted the code but I missed the space after strcat and forgot to add one before PrcFile, sorry ! Why do you strcpy(loc, "") ????? This will do nothing ...

Comment: yes, you are right. But actually the issue is with conversion

Comment: how much do you read on one call?

Comment: It is some setup based. but it ranges from 20 to 150.

Comment: 1. This code does not show how the Bytes parameter is calculated, but that is most likely your problem. There's no reason to think that the conversion affects file I/O. 2. You can use the `%X` format specifier to obtain capital hexadecimal. 3. Contrary to the question title, you are converting ASCII to hex.

Comment: Yes, no reason to effect but it is effecting as I said :(. Your third observation is also correct

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion logic assumes that the number of bytes read will be exactly equal to what you're expecting.  Unfortunately this isn't the case.  Thus in your loop you need to change it to looking at the actual bytes read instead:

```
for (i=0;i<BytesRead;i++)
```

and

```
for (i=0;i<(BytesRead*2);i++)
```

But beyond that because input/output is buffered and you may not get all the bytes you want at once anyway.  So the best thing to do is to put fread itself into a loop so you detect when the actual end is hit, rather than assuming you can read it all in one go:

```
int TotalRead = 0;
int BytesRead;

while(TotalRead < Bytes && (BytesRead = fread(TmpLoc, 1, Bytes - TotalRead,PrcFile)) > 0) {
    /* do your converting and needed stuff here */
    TotalRead += BytesRead;
}
```

That way you'll keep reading to the end of the file.  Or you can always check for reading at most Bytes in size too, of course.

Comment: You pointer right about BytesRead, but even after putting BytesRead, it is not reading whole file.Like I have 34000 bytes file and it read only 16384 bytes

Comment: Did you see the last half of the note about call fread multiple times till it reports 0 or less?

Comment: Well, I can not read it in one go.  I have to read some byte converting them to ASCII then store this to variable for further processing and so on.

Comment: Add a `BytesReadThisPass` variable and add to it until you've read Bytes total.  You can still limit how much you read, but you'll still need to call fread multiple times to be sure to get `Bytes` length.

Comment: Thank for your reply.I am passing bytes to read a parameter. Can you please more specific about what are you saying.

Comment: I've updated it to include a more complete loop that is needed.

Comment: Dear Wes, thanx for your update. Still on reaching certain point [as before] fread return 0. As I said but if I remove my conversion code then it read whole file.